# How to correctly use listSeparatorTextViewStyle for ExpadanbleListView header items?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've spent a lot of time looking for a way to get the default header state indicator (▲/▼) to show on my `ExpadanbleListView` header item (something I would expect to be trivial). Eventually, I've found mention of the `android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle` style. So I tried this in my group view layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/firmwareItemHeader"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the result is wrong - the indicator overlaps with the text:

[image]

How to fix this?

Of note: the `ExpandableListView` has `android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildIndicatorRight"`.

As you can see, my header view layout is a primitive single `TextView`, and it's going to stay that way. I'll happily use a default view with an indicator instead of my own XML, if such a view exists (I couldn't find one).

One can set a custom `@drawable` indicator via `android:groupIndicator` attibute of the list view, but again, I can't find any default value.

Comment: try use **android:layout_width="match_parent"** instead of **"wrap_content"** in your TextView

Comment: @Alexander: no change. It could be because I use `android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildIndicatorRight"` for the list view.

Comment: may be you can set **android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"** in textView or any other drawable

Comment: @Alexander: that doesn't look like the right, Android-default drawable for this item.

Comment: try to add **android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"** and 
        **android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"** into TextView

Comment: @Alexander: nice. I've set the padding to `60dp` as a quick-and-dirty fix, and your way is the right way to do this. Still, it's odd that the `listSeparatorTextViewStyle` doesn't include this. Makes me feel like I'm doing this the wrong way. It shouldn't be so complicated. It can't be.

Comment: But if you use **listSeparatorTextViewStyle** not in **ExpandableListView**

Comment: @Alexander: Sorry, didn't get that, can you rephrase?

Comment: You said "it's odd that the listSeparatorTextViewStyle doesn't include this", but you can use **listSeparatorTextViewStyle** in different cases. So if this param includes padding by default, it affects another developers.